# Current in a semiconductor

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Consider a simple semiconductor device p-n junction diode which is forward biased.Now there will be a current flow in the diode as well as connecting wires.My doubt is will the definition of current hold in diode?I mean suppose current in connecting wires is 5mA.This mean through a given cross-section of wire 5mC charge passes per unit time.Will 5mC charge also pass through each cross-section of the diode?Can current flowing in the diode be defined?

Comment: Current flowing in the diode can clearly be defined. If the charge goes in one side and comes out the other, it goes through the diode (unless it is stored somewhere, like in, say, a capacitor - and junction capacitances can be defined but don't store huge amounts of charge). But, could you clarify why you have doubts that current is defined differently in a diode as opposed to a wire?

Comment: @Jon Custer Actually current in wires is due to free electrons and in diode due to both majority charge carriers+minority charge carriers.This is where my confusion developed as should the current be the same due to both cases?

Comment: Current is still current. And, current in metals often has a hole component as well. (Just for fun, you should realize that current does not flow through a diode - majority carriers from both sides flow into the junction and recombine there.)

Comment: @Jon Custer I think you didn't got my doubt.I am asking if 5mC charge per second enter the diode then will the same 5mC charge pass through each cross-section of the interior of the diode?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The drift velocity is much higher in the semiconductor material than in the lead wires. (That is also why the Hall effect is so much larger in semiconductors, it is due the the larger Lorentz force on the fast charge carriers.)